# How do I replace a json comma with a new line

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

im trying to replace every comma in my json file:

```json
{
  "friends": {
    "count": "9",
    "friends": [
      "Xdevil_blueX",
      "SpectakularBaby_YT",
      "kingdondon96",
      "Xxaland366xX",
      "imbadinarsenal_99",
      "EnderMox2",
      "No0dles_s",
      "cracon999",
      "ionwarrior123"
    ]
  }
}
```

so i need to replace every comma in the friends list with a new line

for example i want the output to be like this (just note im not using node.js)

```
Xdevil_blueX
SpectakularBaby_YT
kingdondon96
Xxaland366xX
imbadinarsenal_99
EnderMox2
No0dles_s
cracon999
ionwarrior123
```

Comment: If you replace the comma with a newline it won't be valid JSON anymore. Please may you explain the issue you have? Also may you provide a sample output you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily do that taking the array 'friends' and turning it into a string while you break the line in each comma. follows like this:

```js
friends.join('\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[
  "Xdevil_blueX",
  "SpectakularBaby_YT",
  "kingdondon96",
  "Xxaland366xX",
  "imbadinarsenal_99",
  "EnderMox2",
  "No0dles_s",
  "cracon999",
  "ionwarrior123"
].join('\n')
```

Comment: Why use map here?

Comment: I gave me the output of `undefined`

Comment: @Petyor I didn't downvote. I also think `forEach` is not good here. `.join('\n')` seems to be a good fit

Comment: @AyomideIlesanmi the output of the above is undefined, but the variable `str` now contains the output that you want

Comment: @AyomideIlesanmi use the `str` variable or declare any of your choice.

Comment: You're likely to get downvote when you answer with code without any explanation how this works and how this answers the question.

Comment: @MeanGreen please keep in mind that when you don't have delete vote privileges you can't recommend deletion to answers like this. You can downvote them, but not recommend delete them.